# Treat dictionary key with multiple characters as "one character"?

Tags: python, dictionary, translate

I'm trying to create a simple "translator" to be able to encrypt/decrypt between binary and "leetspeak" using dictionarys to map keys to values and "translate" between them. It works just fine to "encrypt" one letter to x number of characters (and of course also to decrypt it, as long as the key arent longer than one character) but I noted that stuff breaks when trying to decrypt multiple characters to one and started to thinking about if it's possible in a fairly simple way to treat one key as a single character or something like that.

The only suggestions I've had so far is basically to write something similar to unicode myself and that seems overkill enough since i'm new at this and just learning and that's not something I want to even try to do, at least not at the moment, so basically my question is if it's another way to accomplish the same thing? Even if i have to rewrite the whole thing, using a completely different method than this dict-idea i came up with, it would really be of help.

```
binary_encrypt = {
    "A": "01000001", "B": "01000010", "C": "01000011", "D": "01000100", "E": "01000101",
    "F": "01000110", "G": "01000111", "H": "01001000", "I": "01001001", "J": "01001010",
    "K": "01001011", "L": "01001100", "M": "01001101", "N": "01001110", "O": "01001111",
    "P": "01010000", "Q": "01010001", "R": "01010010", "S": "01010011", "T": "01010100",
     "U": "01010101", "V": "01010110", "W": "01010111", "X": "01011000", "Y": "01011001",
    "Z": "01011010", "Å": "11000101", "Ä": "11000100", "Ö": "11010110",
 
    "a": "01100001", "b": "01100010", "c": "01100011", "d": "01100100", "e": "01100101",
    "f": "01100110", "g": "01100111", "h": "01101000", "i": "01101001", "j": "01101010",
    "k": "01101011", "l": "01101100", "m": "01101101", "n": "01101110", "o": "01101111", 
    "p": "01110000", "q": "01110001", "r": "01110010", "s": "01110011", "t": "01110100",
    "u": "01110101", "v": "01110110", "w": "01110111", "x": "01111000", "y": "01111001", 
    "z": "01111010", "å": "11100101", "ä": "11100100", "ö": "11110110",
 
    "0": "00110000", "1": "00110001", "2": "00110010", "3": "00110011", "4": "00110100", 
    "5": "00110101", "6": "00110110", "7": "00110111", "8": "00111000", "9": "00111001",
    " ": "00100000", # Whitespace-character
 
    "!": "00100001", "\"": "00100010", "#": "00100011", "¤": "10100100", "%": "00100101",
    "&": "00100110", "/": "00101111", "(": "00101000", ")": "00101001", "=": "00111101", 
    "?": "00111111", "§": "10100111", ",": "00101100", ".": "00101110", "-": "00101101", 
    ";": "00111011", ":": "00111010", "_": "01011111", "<": "00111100", ">": "00111110", 
    "|": "01111100", "´": "10110100", "`": "01100000", "@": "01000000", "£": "10100011", 
    "$": "00100100", "€": "10101100", "{": "01111011", "[": "01011011", "]": "01011101", 
    "}": "01111101", "\\": "01011100"
}
 
binary_decrypt = dict([(value, key) for key, value in binary_encrypt.items()])
 
leetspeak_encrypt = {
    "A": "4", "B": "13", "C": "(", "D": "[)", "E": "3",
    "F": "|=", "G": "6", "H": "|-|", "I": "|", "J": ".]",
    "K": "|<", "L": "1", "M": "|Y|", "N": "/\/", "O": "0",
    "P": "|>", "Q": "0,", "R": "|2", "S": "5", "T": "7",
   "U": "[_]", "V": "\/", "W": "\v/", "X": "}{", "Y": "`/",
    "Z": "2", "Å": "A.", "Ä": "A..", "Ö": "0.."        
}
 
leetspeak_decrypt = dict([(value, key) for key, value in leetspeak_encrypt.items()])    
 
language = input("Language? Binary/Leetspeak: ")
mode = input("Mode? Encrypt/Decrypt: ")
string = input("Enter your string you want to en/decrypt: ")

if language == "binary":
    if mode == "encrypt":
        translated_msg = []
        for letter in string:
            translated_msg.append(binary_encrypt.get(letter, letter) + " ")
        translated_msg = "".join(translated_msg)
        print("Done! Here is your encrypted message [EN]CRYPT -> BINARY:")
        print(translated_msg)
    elif mode == "decrypt": 
        translated_msg = []
        for letter in string:
            translated_msg.append(binary_decrypt.get(letter, letter) + " ")
        translated_msg = "".join(translated_msg)
        print("Done! Here is your decrypted message [DE]CRYPT <- BINARY:")
        print(translated_msg)
elif language == "leetspeak":
    if mode == "encrypt":
        string = string.upper()
        translated_msg = []
        for letter in string:
            translated_msg.append(leetspeak_encrypt.get(letter, letter))
        translated_msg = "".join(translated_msg)
        print("Done! Here is your encrypted message [EN]CRYPT -> LEETSPEAK:")
        print(translated_msg)
    elif mode == "decrypt": 
        translated_msg = []
        for letter in string:
            translated_msg.append(leetspeak_decrypt.get(letter, letter))
        translated_msg = "".join(translated_msg)
        print("Done! Here is your decrypted message [DE]CRYPT <- LEETSPEAK:")
        print(translated_msg)
```

Output as expected (example trying to decrypt the key for the value of letter M in leetspeak):

```
> python .\testchiffer.py
Language? Binary/Leetspeak: leetspeak
Mode? Encrypt/Decrypt: decrypt
Enter your string you want to en/decrypt: |Y|
Done! Here is your decrypted message [DE]CRYPT <- LEETSPEAK:
IYI
```

Thanks on beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

I might not have understood exactly what you want here, but can't you just have either another dictionary or directly use binary number notation like instead of storing them as strings use `0b0011001`... ?
You could use a table with only binary numbers or maybe two with string/binary.

Because a string of `0`s and `1`s is only encoding the 0 and 1 character not storing binary values.

Since well, a string of characters can't be treated as "one character".
You could also maybe do a custom class or something like that
Lemme know if I misunderstood your question

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "have another dictionary"? For both the binary and leetspeak-examples above i have 2 dictionarys, one for encrypt and one for decrypt, e.g "M": "|Y|" and "|Y|": "M", i havent tried the other method you mentioned yet i will look into that later today when i get home, but won't the problem remain on the "leetspeak" part still? Sorry if I misunderstood you at some part, I'm not the best at programming-grammar yet :)

Comment: Sorry I'm just not that experienced with encryption stuff and not at all with leetspeak, what I was trying to say is that maybe you could have another dictionary storing the binary values as actual binary values instead of strings so that you can treat them "as on character"